# Connect Android to Python

Tags: android, python, sockets, tcp

I have an Android application that captures an image and Python code that extracts some features from images. I want to connect them to each other (receive the image in Python from the Android application). I read some things about building a TCP Server, but I don't know how to do it and how to start as it's my first time to do something like that.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could have the Android Application save the image to a folder and have the Python file import that image.

Answer (score -1):

You can upload a image to server using any of the database, use python code on server side and you will get the result.

Comment: Why down voted ? Whats the problem in answer ? Please Explain !